# PHP: Display the same array value only once

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have a table called tags which contains the tag_name and the question_id. Just like Stack Overflow, I can insert each tags by exploding them with a comma. That works.

But I also wanted to show all the tags. Let's say this is the result I get after selecting it from the `tags` table.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [tag_name] => tag-1,
        [question_id] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [tag_name] => tag-1,
        [question_id] => 2
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [tag_name] => tag-2,
        [question_id] => 3
    )

)
```

When I iterate through them, I get

```
tag-1
tag-1
tag-2
```

But that's not how I wanted it. I was thinking of something like

```
tag-1 × 2
tag-2
```

How can I achieve that? 
I'm using CodeIgniter but it doesn't really matter, because I only want to understand the logic of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you're trying to count the duplicate entries. So... `COUNT()` them and do a GROUP BY ;-) maybe even using HAVING in conjunction with `COUNT()`. That would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this but something like this should work:

```
<?php
$tag_array = [
    0 => [
        'tag_name' => 'tag-1',
        'question_id' => 1
    ],
    1 => [
        'tag_name' => 'tag-1',
        'question_id' => 2
    ],
    2 => [
        'tag_name' => 'tag-2',
        'question_id' => 3
    ],
];

$count_tags = array();

foreach($tag_array as $v)
{
    if(!isset($count_tags[$v['tag_name']]))
    {
        $count_tags[$v['tag_name']] = 0;
    }

    ++$count_tags[$v['tag_name']];
}

// Sort your tags from hi to low
arsort($count_tags);

foreach($count_tags as $k=>$v)
{
    echo $k.($v > 1 ? ' x '.$v : '').'<br>';
}
```

Outputs:

```
tag-1 × 2
tag-2
```

---

Or you can just do this in SQL:

```
select
    tag_name,
    count(tag_name) as tag_count
from
    tags
group by
    tag_name
order by
    count(tag_name) desc
```

Comment: I saw the edit *lol* seems you saw my comments up there ;-) you didn't have that SQL part there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- haha, yep! I didn't notice the mysqli tag on the question at first so I didn't want to assume OP had access to the data source :-)

Comment: Well, they have a choice ;-)

Comment: I'll give it a try thanks everyone. but just one thing. Does it avoid the other duplicates?

Comment: @mzcoxfde you're welcome. Please see my edit because I added sorting if that's important to you

Answer (score 1):

My answer to the problem:

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        'tag_name' => 'tag-1',
        'question_id' => 1
    ],
    1 => [
        'tag_name' => 'tag-1',
        'question_id' => 2
    ],
    2 => [
        'tag_name' => 'tag-2',
        'question_id' => 3
    ],
];

$count = [];
foreach ($array as $arr)
{
    if (empty($count[$arr['tag_name']]))
    {
        $count[$arr['tag_name']] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $count[$arr['tag_name']]++;

    }
}

foreach ($count as $key => $c)
{
    echo $key . (($c > 1) ? ' x' . $c : '') . '<br>';'
}

// outputs:
tag-1 x2
tag-2
```

Comment: This also might work but it looks that same as MonkeyZeuz's answer

Comment: Guess I forgot to refresh the page before answering, I'll close my answer if you like. (And we've got similar thinking, I suppose)